# How to show runtime permission dialog while app running in background?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-permissions

I made an app locker but the pop-up dialogue doesn't appear because of this.

[Like This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/anRce.png)

I need java code for this case

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_OVERLAY_PERMISSION, Uri.parse("package:"+ act.getPackageName()));
```

not for this case